# Conversion of denary number to binary number problem (Python)

Tags: python, function, binary, division, truncated

Im stuck on a problem where I have to write a function that converts a denary number into a binary number using the repeated division by two algorithm. Steps Include:

- The number to be converted is divided by two.
- The remainder from the division is the next binary digit. Digits are added to the front of the sequence.
- The result is truncated so that the input to the next division by two is always an integer.
- The algorithm continues until the result is 0.

Please click the link below to see what the output should be like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pifUO.png

```
def dentobi(user):
  denary = user
  divide = user / 2
  remainder = user % 2
  binary = remainder
  
  if user != 0:
    print("Denary:", denary)
    print("Divide by 2:", divide)
    print("Remainder:", remainder)
    print("Binary:", binary)
  
user = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
dentobi(user)
```

This is what I have done so far but Im not getting anywhere.

Can someone explain how I would do this?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Ive edited my post, please see what I have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer provided by @user2390182 is functionally correct except that it returns an empty string when *num* is zero. However, I have noted on several occasions that *divmod()* is rather slow. Here are three slightly different techniques and their performance statistics.

```
import time

# This is the OP's original code edited to allow for num == 0
def binaryx(num):
    b = ""
    while num:
        num, digit = divmod(num, 2)
        b = f"{digit}{b}"
    return b or '0'

# This is my preferred solution
def binaryo(n):
    r = []
    while n > 0:
        r.append('1' if n & 1 else '0')
        n >>= 1
    return ''.join(reversed(r)) or '0'

# This uses techniques suggested by my namesake
def binaryy(n):
    r = ''
    while n > 0:
        r = str(n & 1) + r
        n >>= 1
    return r or '0'

M = 250_000

for func in [binaryx, binaryo, binaryy]:
    s = time.perf_counter()
    for _ in range(M):
        func(987654321)
    e = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'{func.__name__} -> {e-s:.4f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
binaryx -> 1.3817s
binaryo -> 0.9861s
binaryy -> 1.6052s
```

Comment: There is no sense to initialize `r` as list, you just wasting memory for no reason, same ternary condition could be written with any sequence (including `str`). And replace `n //= 2` with `n >>= 1`, it should be around hundred of times faster. And replace `if len(r) == 0` with `if r`. And user `reversed(r)` instead of slicing, it won't create one more list in memory. At all just don't use `.append()`, use `.insert()` to first position to form list in proper order. And use `str(n & 1)` instead of this weird condition. Your code is just terrible in comparison with answer you dare to criticize.

Comment: Replacing *r.append('1' if n & 1 else '0')* with *r.append(str(n&1))* slows this down significantly. I don't understand your point about initialisation of *r*. If I'm going to use insert then what would I be inserting into other than a list that I have initialised? I wasn't aware that n //= 2 was significantly slower than n >>= 1. I take that on board. The reason for len(r) == 0 was for clarity. Also, I just changed my test rig to use insert which I find to be slower than append and the subsequent reverse

Comment: Look, you're initializing list `r`, then you build this list and finally you're using this list to form final string. There's no reason to have list in this chain, just form string. `r = ''`  and `r = ('1' if n & 1 else '0') + r` inside loop. Ternary condition in return statement could be easily replaced with simple `r or '0'`.

Comment: I got different result on benchmark showing string buffer option is quite a bit faster. [Code](https://tio.run/##lZDdaoQwEIXvfYphLnYTWsQoLUsh@yKlBLuOmNaMIWa39OltVqs3/aNzM8nJmfOF8e@xG7g6@DBNDbVw6uj0qgTLhwxSjaABcT6@dbYn4EVf3wQqBNsCww4UUD8SYIESbmDcfAzHowY13wPFc@A0OoSrMcs2Zrkx@5T7@PQ9s89r74mbH7i/MRHzl8GyCHShMFIjeim3b6QoY7h2ZAxoDXtjXG3ZmP2Cts4PIUK0jmycFR8sR7EI@dIEfi6vPNxXlVJ3VSHxFsaE9xrbMDhYY9fAZSCZ@OyeKWhVXEvKPxDlfxHlV8Q0fQA).

Comment: Very interesting. I ran your code (Python 3.10.2) and got 0.3862747359999048 (check1) 0.38129006599774584 (check2) so very little difference but check2 slightly faster. Type of CPU? Python version?

Comment: Python 3.9.10, average x64 CPU, Windows 10.

Comment: Python 3.10.2 - 3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W - macOS

Answer (score 0):

One way, using `divmod` to divide by 2 and get the remainder in one step:

```
def binary(num):
    b = ""
    while num:
        num, digit = divmod(num, 2)
        b = f"{digit}{b}"
    return b

binary(26)
'11010'
```

This assumes a positive number but can easily be extended to work for 0 and negatives.

Comment: `return b or "0"` could fix empty string return in case if `num` is zero.